# for_each_zone used in linux system call

Tags: linux-kernel

in a new system call , i want to access each zone's statistics i.e in vm_stat[].

```
#include < linux/mmzone.h >
        my service{


    struct zone *mzone;
        for_each_zone(mzone)
            {
                long l=mzone.vm_stat[NR_FREE_PAGES];
            }

    }
```

gives several errors. im totally confused as to how for_each_zone macro be called from myservice.c..

and secondly, if i want to call any funcion from vmscan.c .. what would be the way to do it..

plzzz help.. 
all my concepts regarding linux need brushing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 things wrong here. First you are declaring `l`inside the for loop. Second `mzone` is a pointer, so you need to use `->` instead of `.` to access `vm_stat`. Plus, instead of `long l` you should use `atomic_long_t l`, which needs `asm-generic/atomic-long.h` included. That said, here's a kernel **module** which works with your example:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mmzone.h>
#include <asm-generic/atomic-long.h>

int __init init_module(void){
 struct zone *mzone;
 atomic_long_t l
 for_each_zone(mzone)
   l = mzone->vm_stat[NR_FREE_PAGES];
 return 0;
}

void __exit clean_module(void){
}
```

Now, for how the `for_each_zone` macro works. It is defined in `linux/mmzone.h` as (kernel 3.1.5):

```
#define for_each_zone(zone)                             \
        for (zone = (first_online_pgdat())->node_zones; \
             zone;                                      \
             zone = next_zone(zone))
```

As you can see it works by receiving a pointer to a `struct zone` and it then expands into a for loop, which will cycle through each zone. Therefore, you can think of it as a simple for loop.

Now, as I understood your question you need to call `my_service` from within the kernel sources. The kernel has several folders where you can put your sources (`fs`, `ipc`, etc..). The quickest way of doing it, is by choosing one of these folders and put your `.c` file inside it. Then you need to change the `Makefile` from that folder so it also compiles your `.c`. After this, you probably want to write a `.h` file to provide your functions to others. I would recommend put it inside `include/linux`. Finally, you'll need to recompile the kernel. Don't forget that if you want modules to use any of your functions/variables you can always use the macro `EXPORT_SYMBOL` to make these available.

Hope this helps