# System call to report memory management statistics

Tags: memory-management, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to create a static system call in the kernel (2.6.18) to report memory management statistics. For example I need to get the number of pages in the active list. I know that there is a struct that contains this information (the zone struct and the field is nr_active). The assignment can be found here: http://www.cs.rochester.edu/users/faculty/sandhya/csc256/assignments/kernel-programming5.html .

How do I access this struct from a system call? I already have the system call working, but where I am stuck is finding the entry point to this data structure.

Comment: explain it properly for better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of googling, I found something useful.
[for_each_zone used in linux system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527127/for-each-zone-used-in-linux-system-call)

The assignment description is very vague, probably on purpose, anyways after looking at mmzone.h I see several macros that can be useful for this assignment.